# How to change the cell appearence of the filter in UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using UltraWinGrid control and I want to customize its filtering.

[image: Custom Filter]

I am able to get all the values from the ValueList property .

```
private void dgridData_BeforeRowFilterDropDown(object sender, BeforeRowFilterDropDownEventArgs e)
{

     // Get each item from the list
     foreach (ValueListItem item in e.ValueList.ValueListItems)
     {
         // Do Something
     }

}
```

I want to show the values in the dropdown ( see picture ) as follows :-

(All)
(Custom)
(Blanks)
(NonBlanks)
*********
*********
*********

**The values after (NonBlanks) should appear as asterisks** .

One of the option I can think is to [attach a masked editor to the current editor](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v10.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~MaskDataMode.html) , to change the display. But I dont know how to attach an editor control in this scenario.

Sharing some links on I was going through :-

1. [Filtering Rows in Ultragrid](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/1224/12746.aspx)
2. [Removing default entries from Infragistics UltraWinGrid RowFilterDropDown](http://blog.trivadis.com/blogs/nicolasmueggler/archive/2008/01/30/removing-default-entries-from-infragistics-ultrawingrid-rowfilterdropdown.aspx)

You are welcom to let me know of other options to acheive the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my pc with Infragistics on it right now. But Couldn't you just loop through the items and change the DisplayText?

```
private void dgridData_BeforeRowFilterDropDown(object sender, BeforeRowFilterDropDownEventArgs e)
{
         // Get each item from the list
         foreach (ValueListItem item in e.ValueList.ValueListItems)
         {
             if (!item.DisplayText.StartsWith("("))
                 item.DisplayText = new String('*', item.DisplayText.Length);
         }

}
```

I'm just typing the code from the top of my head, pardon any errors.

Comment: thanks for your help. I had also done it, but it changes all the text to *, which I dont want . I wanted to remove the duplicates only, I am  not working on this issue anymore, but if I come across any solution in the future, I shall certainly post it.

Answer (score 0):

What should the filtering do after you have changed the list to be strings of asterisk characters?  Are you looking to provide a filter based on the length of the items?